# Inconsistency in Resharper's qunit test runner

Tags: resharper, qunit

I would like to use Resharper's (8.0.2) integrated qunit test runner, but there are some differences when running a test directly in a browser vs running it in a browser using the R# runner:

1. As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178572/qunit-qunit-fixture-div-gets-deleted-running-unit-tests-with-resharper-8), a fixture element is not added, which is needed for UI related tests. As described in the answer, it can be solved by manually adding the element in a module setup + teardown methods.

   Which brings me to the next issue:
2. Resharper only regognizes the [deperecated](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.module/) `setup` and `teardown`, and not their replacements (`beforeEach` and `afterEach`):

> DEPRECATION Note: beforeEach and afterEach were previously named setup and teardown, which still exist and will be removed in QUnit 2.0.0.

```
module("Tests for DOM manipulation", {
    beforeEach: function () { // never called in the R# runner
        $("body").append('<div id="qunit-fixture" />');
    }
});

test('finding qunit-fixture element', function(){
    var elementCount = $('#qunit-fixture').length;
    ok(elementCount, 1);
});
```

Finally, the `test()` callback function doesn't return an `assert` object, i.e:

```
test('foo', function(assert){
    var done = asssert.async(); // assert is undefined in R# qunit runner
    setTimeout(function (){
        ok(1 === 1);
        done();
    }, 500);
});
```

Is there any way to make R# behave more like a "native qunit" test implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly how you want this to work, but I wanted to run a newer version of QUnit than the one that comes bundled with R#.

The simplest solution I had was to include QUnit-1.17.1 into my project, and in the top of my JavaScript test file, include:

```
/// <reference path="../lib/qunit-1.17.1.js" />
```

This will include that file before the rest of the script, so it will essentially overwrite the existing QUnit definition provided by R#.

There might be problems with collisions, but I was able to get this to work:

```
/// <reference path="../lib/qunit-1.17.1.js" />

QUnit.test('this is my test', function(assert) {
    assert.equal(1, 1);
});
```

The test succeeds with the regular R# test runner.

To clarify, the path *../lib/qunit-1.17.1.js* is the file location relative to the test.js file.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This might work, but it's not optimal as you're saying. I actually asked the R# team, and all they told me that the only way to get an updated QUnit runner was to wait until one comes bundled with a future R# release, which is quite a dissapointment IMO.

Comment: I know what you mean, it would be nice if you could tell R# how to configure the test context.